# Why does Tyrell Wellick put on latex gloves in Elliot's apartment?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In the final episode of season 1, Tyrell enters Elliot's apartment to ask him about his plan. He begins to put latex gloves. Earlier in the season, we saw Tyrell put on gloves before beating up the homeless man. The implication is he's going to beat up Elliot to get the information he's after. But Elliot shows him f-society without 1) physical violence, or 2) the apparent threat of physical violence since 1) that was not shown in the scene, and 2) Elliot doesn't know the meaning of the gloves.

Was the threat of violence cut from the scene? If so, why not also cut the gloves? If left in intentionally, is it possible we're meant to assume that because we (the viewers) know the meaning of the gloves, that Elliot does as well (because "we" told him)?

Comment: I thought he wore gloves to stop his fingerprints from getting on anything: he doesn't want to leave evidence behind.

Comment: are there other times he put on the gloves? i only remember the two times i mentioned.

Comment: I don't remember any other times.

Comment: it occurred to me that he did not wear gloves (that i recall) when he strangled the CTO's wife on the roof. though i think that was an accident.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The threat was obvious and present:

> Now, I don't know what you're grand plan is, but I need to, and you're going to tell me.
>   Two days ago, I strangled a woman to death.
>   Just with my hands.
>   It's a strange sensation.
>   Something so tremendous done by something so simple.
>   The first 10 seconds were Uncomfortable.
>   A feeling of limbo.
>   But then your muscles tense.
>   And she struggles and fights, but it almost disappears in the background along with everything else in the world.
>   In that moment, it's just you and absolute power.
>   Nothing else.
>   That moment stayed with me.
>   I thought I'd feel guilty for being a murderer.
>   But I don't.
>   I feel wonder.

And then immediately it cuts to them being at the arcade.

When a seemingly deranged man puts on surgical gloves and tells you he felt wonder while he strangled someone to death, while he's up in your face, the message is clear.

No violence happened, because Elliot didn't resist. He told Tyrell what he needed to know.